# C Levenshtein program works only with txt and pdf file

Tags: c, levenshtein-distance

I'm writing a project that has the task of calculating the Edit distance between two input files.
The goal is to compare any type of file.
The problem comes when I go to run and this is the result.

OUTPUT

---

filedistance distance pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf

EDIT DISTANCE: 216

filedistance distance sample.jpg sample2.jpg

EDIT DISTANCE: 0

filedistance distance file1.txt file2.txt
EDIT DISTANCE: 11

---

With a .txt file or a .pdf file it works fine. It doesn't work with a file other than these.
Obviously the compared files are different, so it is impossible that b.jpg has a distance from c.jpg equal to 0

This is my solution, but I don't see any problem.

I'm going to read the files as binary files, in this way I shouldn't have any problem for any extension.

```
int levenshtein_distance(char *file1, char *file2){
  char *str1 = getString(file1);
  char *str2 = getString(file2);
  int n = (int)strlen(str1) + 1;
  int m = (int)strlen(str2) + 1;
  if (n == 0)
      return m;
  if (m == 0)
      return n;
  int **matrix = matGenerate(str1, n, str2, m);
  int distance = matrix[n - 1][m - 1];
  deallocateMat(n, matrix);
  free(str1);
  free(str2);
  return distance;
}

char *getString(char *file){
  FILE *inputFile = fopen(file, "rb");
  if (inputFile == NULL){
    perror("Could not open file");
    exit(1);
  }
  fseek(inputFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
  long sizeFile = ftell(inputFile);
  rewind(inputFile);
  char *string = calloc(1, sizeFile);
  if (string != NULL){
      fread(string, sizeFile, 1, inputFile);
  }
  fclose(inputFile);
  return string;
}
```

Methods like matGenerate and deallocateMat are used to fill and empty the array. If requested, I can attach them.

I can't understand why it doesn't work with files other than pdf and txt.
Can you help me?

Comment: One problem: `strlen` stops at `\0`.

Comment: Please post the output as text instead of image

Comment: String operations don't work on binary data.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710629/why-my-levenshtein-distance-calculator-fails-with-pdf-file, and at least one other post which I can't find any more.

Comment: `if (n == 0)` If this is intented to detect an empty input string, remember: `int n = ... + 1;`

Comment: Using `strlen()` with data that isn't guaranteed to contain `'\0'` is also bad.

Comment: Levenshtein distance is only meaningful on text files.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` stops at `\0`. You need to return the size somehow. Something like this:

```
struct filebuffer {
    char *data;
    size_t size;
}

struct filebuffer getString (char *file){
    struct filebuffer ret;

    FILE *inputFile = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (inputFile == NULL){
        perror("Could not open file");
        exit(1);
    }
 
    fseek(inputFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
    ret.size = ftell(inputFile);
    rewind(inputFile);
    ret.data = calloc(1, sizeFile);
    if (ret.data != NULL){
        fread(string, sizeFile, 1, inputFile);
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }

    fclose(inputFile);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` function returns number of bytes before first terminating null-character (0x00).

On the other hand, there are high chance that 5th byte of most JPG file is 0x00 because it is higher byte of 2-byte size of header.

An example of header dump of JPG file:

simple dump:

```
0000  FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01
0010  00 01 00 00 FF DB 00 43 00 05 03 04 04 04 03 05
0020  04 04 04 05 05 05 06 07 0C 08 07 07 07 07 0F 0B
0030  0B 09 0C 11 0F 12 12 11 0F 11 11 13 16 1C 17 13
0040  14 1A 15 11 11 18 21 18 1A 1D 1D 1F 1F 1F 13 17
0050  22 24 22 1E 24 1C 1E 1F 1E FF DB 00 43 01 05 05
```

formatted:

```
0000  ★SOI[0]                  FF D8
0002  ★APP[0]                  FF E0
0004  SizeOfThis[0]             00 10
0006  JFIF[0]                   4A 46 49 46 00
000B  MajorRev                  01
000C  MinorRev                  01
000D  Units                     00
000E  XDensity[0]               00 01
0010  YDensity[0]               00 01
0012  ThumbnailWidth            00
0013  ThumbnailHeight           00
0014  ★DQT[0]                  FF DB
0016  SizeOfThis[0]             00 43
0018  PqTq                      00
0019  Quv[0]                    05 03 04 04 04 03 05 04 04 04 05 05 05 06 07 0C
0029  Quv[16]                   08 07 07 07 07 0F 0B 0B 09 0C 11 0F 12 12 11 0F
0039  Quv[32]                   11 11 13 16 1C 17 13 14 1A 15 11 11 18 21 18 1A
0049  Quv[48]                   1D 1D 1F 1F 1F 13 17 22 24 22 1E 24 1C 1E 1F 1E
```

To overcome this issue, you should pass information of file length separately instead of trying to obtain that via `strlen()`.

For example, it can be done like this:

```
int levenshtein_distance(char *file1, char *file2){
  int n, m; /* move size variables here */
  char *str1 = getString(file1, &n); /* add parameter to get size */
  char *str2 = getString(file2, &m); /* add parameter to get size */
  n++;
  m++;
  if (n == 0)
      return m;
  if (m == 0)
      return n;
  /* omit : same as original */
}

char *getString(char *file, int* size){ /* add parameter to pass size */
  /* omit : same as original */
  fclose(inputFile);
  *size = sizeFile; /* pass size */
  return string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try to run the program, the process fails to finish